# Why are bash aliases disabled in non-interactive shells

Tags: bash, openssh

My question **is not how to enable** aliases in non-interactive shells, but rather **why** aliases are disabled by default in non-interactive shells.

My remote host is called `calvino` and after some configuration I am able to open a connection by simply typing:

```bsh
$ calvino
```

I defined some useful aliases on `calvino`, for example:

```bsh
alias now='date "+%T"'
```

When I try to execute `now` on the remote host I got the following error:

```bsh
$ calvino now
bash: now: command not found
```

I eventually managed to make it work moving things around in `calvino`'s `.bashrc`.

My question is, why aliases are disabled by default in non-interactive shells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why aliases are disabled by default in non-interactive shells?

> After researching the issue, I discovered that remote shells are
>   treated differently. While non-interactive Bash shells don’t normally
>   run ~/.bashrc commands at start-up, a special case is made when the
>   shell is Invoked by remote shell daemon:
>
> > Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the
> >     remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd. If
> >     Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes
> >     commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and is readable. It will
> >     not do this if invoked as sh. The --norc option may be used to inhibit
> >     this behavior, and the --rcfile option may be used to force another
> >     file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd generally invoke the shell
> >     with those options or allow them to be specified.

...

> The main benefit I can see to having .bashrc sourced when running a (non-interactive) remote command is that shell functions can be run. However, most of the commands in a typical .bashrc are only relevant in an interactive shell, e.g., aliases aren’t expanded unless the shell is interactive.

...

> Most of the statements in a typical .bashrc are only useful for an interactive shell – not when running remote commands with rsh or ssh. In most such situations, setting shell variables, aliases and defining functions isn’t desired – and printing any text to standard out is actively harmful if transferring files using programs such as scp or sftp. Exiting after verifying that the current shell is non-interactive is the safest behaviour for .bashrc.

Read the source link below for additional discussion.

Source [Why does bashrc check whether the current shell is interactive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257613), answer by [Anthony G - justice for Monica](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22812/anthony-g-justice-for-monica)